# Efficient data wrangling with missing data in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, melt, dcast

I have a data.table similar to the following:

```
foo  bar  a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 b4 c1 c2 A_1 A_2 A_3 C_1 C_2
m    19   0  1  2  2  1  3  0  0  2  25  33  61  50  50
f    30   1  2  1  0  4  2  1  2  2  10  43  30  45  73 
n    22   0  2  2  1  3  1  0  1  2  7   84  33  12  40
```

I would like to transform this to a long format, with a row for each lowercase letter variable. At the same time, I would like to carry along also uppercase variables that match the lowercase ones, and introduce NAs when there is no match. Here is a snippet of the end result:

```
foo bar lower lower_value upper upper_value
m   19  a1    0           A_1   25
m   19  a2    1           A_2   33
...
f   30  b4    1           B_4   NA
...
n   22  c2    2           C_2   40
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

EDIT:
here the data.table for reference:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  foo = c("m", "f", "n"),
  bar = c(19, 30, 22),
  a1 = c(0, 1, 0),
  a2 = c(1, 2, 2),
  a3 = c(2, 1, 2),
  b1 = c(2, 0, 1),
  b2 = c(1, 4, 3),
  b3 = c(3, 2, 1),
  b4 = c(0, 1, 0),
  c1 = c(0, 2, 1),
  c2 = c(2, 2, 2),
  A_1 = c(25,10,7),
  A_2 = c(33,43,84),
  A_3 = c(61,30,33),
  C_1 = c(50,45,12),
  C_2 = c(50,73,40)
)
```

Comment: In the expected output, 2nd row: this `A_1   33` should be `A_2   33` ?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion! I have edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

here is a potential solution, but I am sure there could be one more efficient way to deal with this

```
melted_dt <- melt(dt, value.name = "lower_value", variable.name = "lower",
                  measure.vars = patterns(lower = "^[a-z]\\d+$")) # melt by lowercase

melted_dt[,upper := toupper(gsub("^([a-z])(\\d+)$", "\\1_\\2", lower))] # create uppercase name variable
melted_dt[,upper_value := ifelse(upper %in% names(melted_dt), get(upper), as.double(NA)), 1:nrow(melted_dt)] # search through the melted data.table to get the uppercase value
melted_dt[, grep("^([A-Z])_\\d+$", names(melted_dt)) := NULL] # drop the old uppercase columns
```

Answer (score 2):

Merge two melts?

```
library(data.table)

merge(
  melt(dt, c("foo", "bar"), names(dt)[3:11], "lower", "lower_value"),
  melt(dt, c("foo", "bar"), names(dt)[12:16], "upper", "upper_value")[
    , lower := tolower(gsub("_", "", upper))
  ], by = c("foo", "bar", "lower"), all = TRUE
)[is.na(upper), upper := toupper(lower)][]
#>     foo bar lower lower_value upper upper_value
#>  1:   f  30    a1           1    A1          10
#>  2:   f  30    a2           2    A2          43
#>  3:   f  30    a3           1    A3          30
#>  4:   f  30    b1           0    B1          NA
#>  5:   f  30    b2           4    B2          NA
#>  6:   f  30    b3           2    B3          NA
#>  7:   f  30    b4           1    B4          NA
#>  8:   f  30    c1           2    C1          45
#>  9:   f  30    c2           2    C2          73
#> 10:   m  19    a1           0    A1          25
#> 11:   m  19    a2           1    A2          33
#> 12:   m  19    a3           2    A3          61
#> 13:   m  19    b1           2    B1          NA
#> 14:   m  19    b2           1    B2          NA
#> 15:   m  19    b3           3    B3          NA
#> 16:   m  19    b4           0    B4          NA
#> 17:   m  19    c1           0    C1          50
#> 18:   m  19    c2           2    C2          50
#> 19:   n  22    a1           0    A1           7
#> 20:   n  22    a2           2    A2          84
#> 21:   n  22    a3           2    A3          33
#> 22:   n  22    b1           1    B1          NA
#> 23:   n  22    b2           3    B2          NA
#> 24:   n  22    b3           1    B3          NA
#> 25:   n  22    b4           0    B4          NA
#> 26:   n  22    c1           1    C1          12
#> 27:   n  22    c2           2    C2          40
#>     foo bar lower lower_value upper upper_value
```

Data

```
dt <- data.table(
  foo = c("m", "f", "n"),
  bar = c(19, 30, 22),
  a1 = c(0, 1, 0),
  a2 = c(1, 2, 2),
  a3 = c(2, 1, 2),
  b1 = c(2, 0, 1),
  b2 = c(1, 4, 3),
  b3 = c(3, 2, 1),
  b4 = c(0, 1, 0),
  c1 = c(0, 2, 1),
  c2 = c(2, 2, 2),
  A1 = c(25,10,7),
  A2 = c(33,43,84),
  A3 = c(61,30,33),
  C1 = c(50,45,12),
  C2 = c(50,73,40)
)
```